# Is there a way to bring two date manipulations into one column when writing a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, data-manipulation

Sorry for the noob question guys! I'm fairly new when it comes to querying databases. 
Well, in short, I'm trying to calculate Month over Month. I wanted to create a column for sales that are essentially pushed one month allowing me to create the calculation for MoM by 
((SalesColumn - PushedSales) / PushedSales) * 100.

My goal is to first and foremost push the Month part of the date by 1 Month and second to change the day part to 1st of the month.

What I'm trying to accomplish is finding a way to accumulate these two statements.

```
DATEADD(MONTH, 1, Order_Date) & DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(Order_Date), MONTH(Order_Date), DAY(0))
```

PART 1:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, Order_Date), Sales
FROM Orders
ORDER BY Order_Date
```

PART 2:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(Order_Date),MONTH(Order_Date),DAY(0)), Sales
FROM Orders
ORDER BY Order_Date
```

What I've done is completed PART 1:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, Order_Date), Sales
FROM Orders
ORDER BY Order_Date
```

And Created a view,

Then using that view I've done PART 2:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(Order_Date), MONTH(Order_Date), DAY(0)),[Sales]
FROM Orders
ORDER BY Order_Date
```

Which gives me the right answer except feels like a very inefficient way to manipulate the dates.

Comment: any sample data with example would be helpful...

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Take a look at this post from [Spaghetti DBA](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips and tricks to make it easier for you to get an answer. Use the `edit` link below your question to modify it.

Comment: @EricBrandt Thanks I'll read through that

Comment: @ChaitanyaKotha So I'm using Tableau Sample Data (Superstore - community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-1236 ) i hope this helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLServer 2012+ has a function EOMonth that returns the last day of the month, of the date you pass in. Adding one day to this gets you the start of the next
month (there is no SOMonth corollary alas)

```
DATEADD(Day, 1, EOMonth(Order_Date))
```

Pass in 23-Jan-2000 to this, it will EOMonth it to 31-Jan-2000 then add one day to get you to 1-Feb-2000

You don't need to create views to use the output of one function as input to another, just chain(nest) the functions:

```
A(B(C(column)))
```

This calls function C and passes in column, then takes the output from C and passes it to B, then takes the output from B and passes it to A

You'd be wise to format (indent) your code nicely if you're going to nest a lot of function calls, each with arguments

Comment: Awesome! thinks worked perfectly as well! And definitely taken note of using nested as well!!

Comment: If an answer is correct for you don't forget to mark it so by clicking the grey arrow so it turns green. You can also upvote any number of helpful answers including the one you accept with the tick

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, I think this gets you what you want:  `dateadd(month,1,dateadd(day,1-day(Order_Date),Order_Date))`